# is Key-Value a acceptable in this case?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design

There is a backend module which simply sends out system requests to different service providers and the partner would be changed frequently. We plan to store the request and request payload into separate tables, one is the request table which contains request id, partner, and request status etc.. another one stores the payload information.

For the payload information table, there are 2 kinds of design came out.

1) stored payload properties like key-value pair
    pros: when adding a new provider, the table schema no need to change
       cons: need extra handling for casting data to a program object

[SQL Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b1ae/2)

2) create a column for each payload property
   pros: easy to read when selecting data
   cons: the table schema would be expanded a lot

[SQL Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/99128/4)

Would like to know which approach is more reasonable and appreciate your suggestion if you have any good design. cheers.

Comment: When designing a database there is always a trade off between memory usage and speed.  You can always put all the data in one table but when there are empty entries you are using memory (for the null cell) and possibly repeating the same data.  When you use more than one table you use less memory but then getting data is slower because you have to do joins.  So the 1st example you could have null parameters while in 2nd case you need to use a join to combine parameters with the same ID.

Comment: definitely not the second approach. That doesn't even pass first normal form.

Comment: THis sounds like an auditing of the requests. Since the payload is very specific to the request to different service providers and the partner, I prefer just to persist it in one column as json or xml. I guess the details of the payload is rarely consumed by other applications.

Comment: I would go with design #1 as more generic.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including [mre]s, tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Make your post self-contained.

Comment: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Comment: There are other options as well: Using an `nvarchar` column to store payload as the json-serialized data, or using an xml column to store xml serialized data. All 4 are valid options, it depends on your needs.